# Forge viewer coordinate units and mapping those to a ThreeJS scene

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to show HTML content in 3D alongside a Forge mode using the ThreeJS CSS3dRenderer (https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/renderers/CSS3DRenderer).

An example of the functionality: http://learningthreejs.com/data/2013-04-30-closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/index.html

In purely a normal ThreeJS context the the steps needed for that are:

1. Create a ThreeJS scene #1 for the DOM content.
2. Create another scene #2 for the 3D content.
3. Add CSS3DObjects with the HTML content into scene #1
4. Add a **matching** 3D element into scene #2 with blending enabled. This makes the HTML content able to occlude the objects in scene #2.
5. Add other 3D objects into scene #2.
6. Render #1 with CSS3DRenderer and #2 with the normal WebGLRenderer.

In the Forge viewer context scene #2 is replaced with an overlay scene.

I applied the tricks featured here https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/transparent-background-viewer-long-last to make the CSS scene visible through the viewer scene and that works ok, except for the strange effect that when the renderer alpha is enabled elements in the overlay scene are only rendered when the occlude the Forge model.

The problem I'm having is point 4. In the case of two normal ThreeJS scenes the position, rotation and scale of the CSS3DObject in scene #1 can just be copied to the object in scene #2 and they match perfectly. Not so between a ThreeJS scene and the viewer's overlay scene as the units don't match up. (Or that's how I've reasoned it.)

Is there some way I can transform between these units?

Comment: Can you post your code and also some screenshots so I can pass on to our Engineering for workaround/fix?

Comment: I edited the transparent background example to include the CSS3D content: https://jsbin.com/nawonomixu/1/edit?html,js,output . If you rotate the scene you can see the overlay objects against the model. I applied some guessed offset values to get them visible. For some reason when you zoom the Forge scene the CSS3D content is not effected at all even if it's rendered with the same camera.

Comment: Tks! Just passed on to Engineering for comments - will get back soon.

Answer (score 0):

According to our Engineering - hats off for Cleve to put the demo together:

> The camera you are using NOP_VIEWER.impl.camera isn't a THREE camera. It is a UnifiedCamera defined by LMV to hold both a perspective and orthographic camera. You need to get the right camera from the UnifiedCamera and use that for the render. Just realized that the CSS3DRenderer was taken from a more recent version of THREE.js and it assumes things that aren't true about THREE.js r71 that LMV uses. I noticed that it uses camera.isPerspectiveCamera to decide when a camera is perspective, That isn't defined in r71 which uses instance of THREE.PerspectiveCamera.

```
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 4000
    );
```

The CSS3DRenderer renders into a flat plane that is composited with the LMV 3D scene. I found an example that faked putting the CSS3D scene with a WebGL scene by zapping transparent holes in the WebGL scene where CSS3D objects were in front of the WebGL scene. This is the example: https://codepen.io/Fyrestar/pen/QOXJaJ

Comment: Yes, that example is pretty much what I've been doing so far. The problem is aligning the holes when Forge viewer is in the mix.

Comment: I managed to tweak my example so that the CSS3D scene renders with the correct Viewer camera and the blending overlays are positioned correctly on the CSS objects: https://jsbin.com/xexoyuyogu/1/edit?js,output But it seems that the blending doesn't work (the viewer is somehow blocking it?) If you switch the opacity of the "holes" to more than zero you can see that they are in the correct places. But the CSS3D scene still isn't visible through them.

Comment: Engineering suggested to try make the background transparent to overcome this - see how [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/transparent-background-viewer-long-last)

Comment: I have already done that from the beginning, otherwise the CSS3D content wouldn't be visible at all. The only problem that still remains is that the blending doesn't affect the Forge object, i.e. the "holes" don't cut through it.

Comment: No insights on the blending problem?